# Split simulink path with // in it.

Tags: regex, matlab, path, split, simulink

I would like to split a `Simulink` path that looks like this: `"a/b/c//d"`. It should split to `[a,b,c/d]`. How would the regular expression look like?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
>> strrep(regexp('a/b/c//d', '(([^/]|//)*)(?=/[^/]|$)', 'match'), '//', '/')
ans = 
    'a'    'b'    'c/d'
```

The regular expression can be understood as follows: the first part matches any not-slashes (`[^/]`) OR double-slashes, giving the piece `([^/]|//)`. We want any number of those, so we need a `*`, followed by EITHER a slash-then-not-slash OR the end of the string (`/[^/]|$`). We use the lookahead operator `(?= ... )` do do that.

The strrep is to replace `//` with `/` in the result. Maybe that can be done in the same call to `regexp`, but it's complicated enough already for my taste.